# Feature class and field names contains blank records in text file

Tags: arcpy

I want to print all feature class names along with field names from a GDB, which are having empty/blank records in text file for user. Fields in feature classes are not same. So I want to skip some particular fields which are not requited to check for empty records. Below is my code and I don't know how to skip some fileds

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env 

env.workspace =  r"C:\Users\Test\Basemap.gdb\ROAD"

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# want to find empty records for below list of feature classes
fields = ["S_CODE","CATEGORY"]

f=open(r'C:\Users\test\List_GDB\Empty_rec.txt','w')
for fc in fclist:
    
    bad_list = []
  
    for field in fields:
        #print (fields)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0] in ["", None, " "]:
                    bad_list.append(field)
                    break
               
    f.writelines(fc+"contains empty records in"+str(bad_list)+"\n")

f.close()
```

[image]

Above is GDB structure. Please suggest  how to skip particular fields (Ex: CODE, ADDRESS etc) in all feature classes while checking for empty records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could omit specific fields using an `if` statement within a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if x.name not in ["CODE","ADDRESS"]]
```

Comment: In my others words, Each feature class in GDB, having some extra fields which are not required to check for empty records. So Intentionally I want skip some specific fields which will be specified at time of running code and also results to be written for text file.

Comment: This is working